# Scrapy wont connect to MSSQL database

Tags: python, sql-server, scrapy, pymssql

**Fixed**

My spider is fully working and I can export the data to JSON, CSV and to a MongoDB. However, since I will be dealing with large chunks of data, I would like to use MSSQL. I've browsed through google and stackoverflow in order to find a solution, but despite many attempts, scrapy wont connect to the database. My brother, a SQL developer, helped me setting up a local database which I could use to store my data on. So I am pretty sure that the database (which is very basic) is set-up correctly.

I am currently hosting the SQL server locally on my desktop with my desktop its username. I haven't set a password and my database is called "kaercher". I'd like to export the data to the table called "products_tb". I have given myself full sysadmin access, so that should be more than enough.

Any of you have any experience with MSSQL?

**Made it working using pymssql**

**pipelines.py**

```
import pymssql

class KrcPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymssql.connect(host='DESKTOP-P1TF28R', user='sa', password='123', database='kaercher')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO products_tb(productid, category, name, description, price, timestamp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                            (item['productid'], item['category'], item['name'], item['description'], item['price'], item['timestamp']))
        self.conn.commit()

        return item
```

**How I found my driver version**

```
for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
    print(driver)

SQL Server
SQL Server Native Client 11.0
SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0
ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver
MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy


class KrcItem(scrapy.Item):
    productid=scrapy.Field()
    name=scrapy.Field()
    description=scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
    producttype=scrapy.Field()
    timestamp=scrapy.Field()
    category=scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'krc.pipelines.KrcPipeline': 300}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be connecting over TCP/IP, which may not be enabled.  Using SQL Server Configuration Manager enable TCP/IP and ensure the instance is listening on port 1433.

Then you'll need to switch to Windows Integrated Auth, not username/password, if you're connecting with your Windows user.

Also `pyodbc` is the recommended library for connecting to SQL Server.

The posted code looks fine.  And this works for me:

```
import pyodbc


cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=tempdb;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

create_table_query = '''create table #products_tb (productid int, category varchar(20), name varchar(20), description varchar(20), price float, timestamp datetime)'''

cursor.execute(create_table_query)

insert_query = '''INSERT INTO #products_tb (productid, category, name, description, price, timestamp)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);'''
item = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in item:

    row = [i,"SomeCat","SomeName","A thing", 12.4, "20190101"]
    values = (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5])

    cursor.execute(insert_query, values)

cnxn.commit()  

result = cursor.execute("select * from #products_tb")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

print(rows)
```

Comment: Hello @David Browne - Microsoft. First of all I would like to thank you for your quick and helpful answer! I have followed your steps and made some progress. I believe I established a connection and I no longer receive an error that stops my spider from crawling data. However, nothing is being sent to my database (table remains empty). I have never used pyodbc, so this is all new to me. I have watched a couple videos and read a few helpful tutorials and tried a few chunks of code. But unfortunately, the result is the same. I have updated my code and the logs from the scrapy terminal.

Comment: Hello @David Browne - Microsoft . Thank you once again for your helpful answer. I updated my code and managed to verify that the connection with the database has been established. I also managed to create a new table called "products_tb" with the `create_table_query`. However, I seem to have a problem with how I select the data which has to be sent to the database. Do I use my items.py file for this as shown in the code above?

Comment: I made it working with pymssql, I couldn't get it working with pyodbc though. However, your solution did help me achieve this progress. Thank you very much. :)